# Доступ к елементам массива, которые являются экземплярами классов, которые связаны между собой

Tags: java, массивы, классы, наследование

Я хочу сделать игру платформер (используя Processing) и столкнулся с такой проблемой. У меня есть 2 типа блоков: стационарные (неподвижные) и те которые двигаются туда сюда по определённому маршруту

Вот класс неподвижного блока

```java
public class Block{
  AABB aabb;
  Block(int x, int y, int w, int h){
    aabb = new AABB(x, y, x+w, y+h);
  }

  void draw(){
    rect(aabb.min.x, aabb.min.y, aabb.getWidth(), aabb.getHeight());
  }
}
```

А вот класс двигающегося блока

```java
class MovingBlock extends Block{
  PVector vel, A, B;

  MovingBlock(int x, int y, int w, int h, PVector B, float speed){
    super(x, y, w, h);

    this.A = aabb.min.copy();
    this.B = B.copy();

    B.sub(aabb.min).setMag(speed);

    this.vel = B;
  }

  void update(){
    aabb.moveByVector(vel);

    if (aabb.min.copy().sub(A).magSq() < 0.25 || aabb.min.copy().sub(B).magSq() < 0.25){
      vel.mult(-1);
    }
  }
}
```

И вот в чем проблема - я храню все эти блоки в ArrayList`е

```java
ArrayList<Block> blocks;
```

Когда я в игровом цикле прохожусь по ним, мне надо сделать вот такую вещь:

```java
for (Block block : blocks){
  //какой-то код
  if (block instanceof MovingBlock){
    player.vel = block.vel.copy();
  }
}
```

Но при попытке запустить Processing выдаёт такой текст:

```
vel cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

Comment: player.vel = ((MovingBlock) block).vel.copy();

Comment: Спасибо, заработало.

Comment: Если заработало оцени совет и закрой вопрос.

Comment: У вас уже на этом этапе проблемы архитектурой. Ваш список типизирован классом Block, это логично, ведь вы хотите хранить в нем все блоки (движущиеся и недвижущиеся). Проблема в том, что теперь Вам каждый раз нужно вызывать instanceof в цикле. В этом случае ваше наследование вообще теряет смысл, полиморфизм не работает.Попробуйте сделать класс Block абстрактным, а от него наследуйте 2 класс-движущиеся и недвижущиеся блоки.Общую логику в базовый класс, а вот эту строку кода player.vel = block.vel.copy(); вынесите в отдельный метод,который у класса Block сделайте абстрактным.И никаких instanceof